# data type of elements in pandas dataframe is not consistent with actual data type

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, datetime

I have a pandas dataframe with a "datetime" column for which when I run df.info(), Dtype is shown as Object. However, if I check each value, they are all <class `datetime.datetime`> why is it inconsistent and how can I make it datetime or idealy <class `pandas._libs.tslibs.timestamps.Timestamp`>?

Comment: Without an [mre] it might be hard to help. ... [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples)

Comment: Might be some row of your column contain "none " or something else, by the way could you plz show your dataframe if possible.

Comment: Do your dates contain multiple different time zones / UTC offsets?

Comment: I cant really provide the data Im working with. I did think of None and those are removed completely. I even ran df["date_dtype"] = df.date.apply(lambda x: type(x)) and they seem to be all datetime.datetime.

Comment: there are, however, some dirty data where year = 4024, etc. not sure if it corrupts the data?

Answer (score 0):

Without providing data in your example, you could try this code to check all cells if they have the same type:

```
 df['column_name'].apply(type).eq(datetime.datetime).all()
```

If the previous line returns False that means you have some cells not having datetime type.

To convert this column to `<class pandas._libs.tslibs.timestamps.Timestamp>`, you could use this:

```
from pandas._libs.tslibs.timestamps import Timestamp
df['column_name'] = Timestamp(df['column_name'])
```